# Pass user's input from textarea(all rows) to URL

Tags: html, url, textarea

I know how to pass only the first row of a textarea to URL.But is it possible to pass all of the rows that user may have inserted to URL?Probably i will need javascript.

```
<form id="form1" action="http://site.com/" target="_blank">
<textarea rows="5" name="abc"></textarea>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PE8Ly/

Comment: <form id="form1" action="http://site.com/" target="_blank">
    <textarea rows="5" name="abc"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the code provided already does what is being asked.

Comment: When you submit that form, the entire content of the textarea will be submitted, not just the first line.

Comment: no it passes only the first row.not all of the rows on URL.And i didnt insult you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PE8Ly/

Comment: @openc — No, it passes all the data. `site.com` then discards the extra lines and redirects.

Comment: ok Quentin i want to show all of the textarea data in URL.

Comment: @openc — Then you need to change the server side code of `site.com`

Comment: How the url then after passing 2 lines of textarea, can give me a example ?

Comment: Change `site.com` to `example.com` (which doesn't redirect) and submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

[Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) is correct. Your code already passes the whole text of the `textarea` element.

The `site.com` removes the extra content.

Try changing your

```
action="http://site.com"
```

to

```
action="http://localhost"
```

or something like this, and you'll notice the whole content is passed with rows separated by `%0D%0A` due to the URL encoding.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uX233/2/)

`%0D` is for `carriage return` and `%0A` is for `line feed`

So, you need to parse the data accordingly on the page that actually receives the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have done some changes from Özkan ÖZLÜ code

```
$(function()
  {
  $("#btn_go").click(
  function()
      {
          var txt = "line1=" + $("textarea").val();

            for(i = 0; i < $("textarea").attr("rows"); i++)
            {
                txt = txt.replace("\n","&line" + (i+2) + "=");
            }                      
          $("form").attr("action", "?" + txt);          
      }
  );
});
```

Comment: thanks but probably noone has understood what i want.I want textarea content to be transferred in the URL but in a new page not showing in a div the url in the same page.i knew how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/uuaX7/10/)

This is my attempt using jQuery:

**HTML**

```
<form action="http://site.com" action="get" target="_blank">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="go" id="btn_go" />
</form>
<div></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
$("#btn_go").click(

function () {
    var txt = "line1=" + $("textarea").val();
    var lines = txt.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
    var count = lines.length;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        txt = txt.replace("\n", "&line" + (i + 2) + "=");
    }
    $("div").html(txt);
    window.location.href = $("form").attr("action") + "?" + txt;
});
});
```

Comment: @openc codes updated. This should work in an altenative way. It is not submitting, it redirects isntead.

Comment: again it doesnt work.Check your fiddle and first make target="_blank" in order to see how url appears in new page

Comment: @openc I checked with FireBug. no problem.